# IF-THEN-ELSE using jquery query builder

Tags: jquery, query-builder

We are using [this](http://querybuilder.js.org/) jquery plugin to build the sql. Would like to know if it can also be customized to create sql such as following

```
IF column_field = '1' THEN 
   SUNDAY;  
ELSE  
   WEEKDAY; 
END IF;
```

Creating `column_field = 1` should be simple. Including the conditions after it will be a challenge. Any inputs?

Comment: I would also be interested in such a solution. Is there already a solution or an alternative that works?

Answer (score 0):

Although not the cleanest way, created something like following by using 2 components as below. So, here if `name` = `Shirt` then set the category as `Clothes`.
Requires some special handling for disabling add rule/group buttons & data saving. But it works.

If...
[image]

Then...

[image]